# Create an auto generated number that starts with the year today 2022 followed by 5 digits like 202200001?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres SQL, I'm trying to create an auto-generated number in the range 202200001 - 202299999 (like `2022ddddd` where `2022` is a fixed prefix followed by a 5-digit zero-padded sequential number).
Example: if the sequential number is 1 then the result shall be `202200001`.

Comment: When the year 2023 arrives, do you want the sequence to start generating numbers from `202300001`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to persist, use a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

`create sequence some_name minvalue 202200000 maxvalue 202299999`

If you need this for a single query, use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)

`select * from generate_series(202200000, 202299999)`

Comment: What happens when a new year rolls over?

Comment: @Bohemian I wonder that myself, but I don't know what the OP is using it for. Ask them.